# What is the difference between following lines of code?

Tags: r, levels

Here's the code

```
levels(data[,7])           ## to output the levels of a column in a vector
levels(data[,7])[data[,7]] ## this is what I am not 100% sure what does it do
```

I think second one just gives back a vector of non-duplicate values (as far as what I got). Any clarification would be appreciated.

Comment: The second one simply turns `data[,7]` into a character vector, just like `as.character(data[,7])` would.

Comment: Check `with(iris, identical(as.character(Species), levels(Species)[Species]))`

Answer (score 0):

The first line shows the levels of the factor variable in data[,7] - that is, the unique values of that factor.

The second line uses the values in data[,7] to index the unique levels. Which, in this case, just gives you back data[,7].

It's a useful construct if instead of levels you have something like a vector of colors that you want to use for different points in a plot.

```
> levels(data[,2])[data[,2]]
 [1] "a" "b" "b" "b" "c" "b" "a" "a" "b" "b" "c" "b" "a" "c" "a" "c" "a" "a" "a" "a"
> c("red", "blue", "green")[data[,2]]
 [1] "red"   "blue"  "blue"  "blue"  "green" "blue"  "red"   "red"   "blue"  "blue" 
[11] "green" "blue"  "red"   "green" "red"   "green" "red"   "red"       "red"   "red"
```

Answer (score 0):

`levels` is a function that provides access to the levels attribute of a variable. Which basically are unique obs. as in below example

```
df <- data.frame(websites = c("git", "git", "python", "R", "python", 
"stackoverflow", "R"))
df
       websites
1           git
2           git
3        python
4             R
5        python
6 stackoverflow
7             R

str(df)

'data.frame':   7 obs. of  1 variable:
$ websites: Factor w/ 4 levels "git","python",..: 1 1 2 3 2 4 3

levels(df[,1]) # this basically gives you the unique levels( or obs)in the variable.
#if you want to replace specific observations the easy way to do that is 
`levels(df[,1]) <- c("git", "veg", "R", "drink")`
```

Now,

```
(df[,1])[df[,1]]
# this is something like accessing values by passing the index like this..
`df[,1][1:6]`# in the prior case you are passing the names itself.
# hence, when you call function levels you are basically calling all the 
# obs, and the levels of that variable
[1] git           git           python        R             python        stackoverflow
[7] R            
Levels: git python R stackoverflow
```